# WP7 market place reports "Exception(s) Applied: None"?

Tags: windows-phone-7, exception, report, marketplace

The Wp7 marketplace result pdf shows in summary "Exception(s) Applied: None". What does this mean. Should I write code to handle unhandled exceptions Or what I am doing is right.
The App is not rejected due to this, but I want to know what this means.

Thanks,
Kanaya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you have not applied for any technical exceptions. These are a request for your application to not be tested against certain market place policy criteria. You can see some details about this on the [Certification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202928%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) section of the FAQ (Under sections 3 and 4) as well as how to apply for exceptions.